# Django admin's filter_horizontal (& filter_vertical) not working

Tags: python, django, django-admin, filtering

I'm trying to use ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal and ModelAdmin.filter_vertical for ManyToMany field instead of select multiple box but all I get  is:
[image]

My model:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    #...
    production_companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company, verbose_name="компании-производители")
    #...
```

My admin:

```
class TitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("original_name",)}
    filter_horizontal = ("production_companies",)
    radio_fields = {"state": admin.HORIZONTAL}
    #...
```

The javascripts are loading OK, I really don't get what happens. Django 1.1.1 stable.

Answer (score 14):

I finally got the solution. The problem was with the field's verbose name - it was str instead of unicode. Moving to unicode helped.

Thanks :-)

Comment: It would take hours for me to find out.

Comment: Models's `verbose_name="Catégorie"` becomes `verbose_name=u"Catégorie"`. 1 character fix, awesome! @negus, you're a genius. I always forget to double check strings with accents in python! This was getting very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this kind of answer. I just found out the value of 'filter_horizontal' must be a list or tuple. 
So this code:

```
filter_horizontal = ("production_companies",)
```

should be changed to:

```
filter_horizontal = ("production_companies", "production_companies")
```

Comment: Both your examples are tuples! Duplicating the field name is unnecessary, just use the first form with the trailing comma or a list with square brackets. To be clear ("example") is a string not a tuple but ("example",) is a tuple containing a single string.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential cause for `filter_horizontal` not working is overriding `form.media` property that includes the necessary JavaScript files for the widget.